# Replace one layer with another in multiple Photoshop projects

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I am creating a series of banners in five sizes. 
Each banner size represents its own .psd file. 
There is a logo on all banners and each series contains a different logo.

Till now I inserted all logos manually for all banner sizes separately. 
Is there a way, that I can change all banners at once?

I am using Photoshop CS6.

Something similar (not really the same thing) exists in AfterEffects called "Replace footage".

Regards!

Comment: Hi user2375263, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. You might want to look into using InDesign for this functionality. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They actually added this feature in the newest installment of Photoshop CC (14.2). You can see more info:

[See linked smart objects](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/create-smart-objects.html)

I am aware of this feature but have not yet used it for anything. Still you should be using indesign. Note,you probably need to script this anyway as you have many legacy files that need updating.

**PS**: Its amazing how long it took them to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You should really be using Illustrator for this if you plan to send it to the printer because your files will be huge but you didnt mention if this was for web or print.  I would suggest making them vector if you can that way if you ever need to use them again but in a different size you can resize without loosing any quality.

Since that wasnt your question.  You can complete the above in an action or script it.  If you dont know how to script then I would suggest creating an action on your layer that is named logo.

Another approach is using InDesign and creating a master page for everything that is to be duplicated and just placing the logo on each "page".

Comment: They actually added this into the newest photoshop cc

Comment: Thanks for advice! Have never used scripting or action, and will defenetly look into it. Banners are for web only and need to be lightweight.

Comment: are these banners for web or print?

Comment: For web only and need to be under 50 kB (no problem at all)

Comment: then why not use Illustrator and output as an SVG with a PNG fallback?

Comment: I joined an existing projects, and I received templates in .psd only. Do you think it is worth the time to make new templates in AI, or is it maybe better to get the new PS as mentioned above?